# Comparing one value across multiple rows in one data frame with values across multiple rows in a second data frame

Tags: r

Scenario:

2-column dataframe_1 (300,000 rows)

head(dataframe_1):

CHR POS

1 2000

1   3000

2       1500

3       3000

3-column dataframe_2 (300 rows)

head(dataframe_2):

CHR     POS_START   POS_END

1       1500        2500

1       3200        4000

2       1200            1600

2       2000        2200

3       5000        5500

4       1000        1200

The goal is to take dataframe_1 and compare the POS column of each row against dataframe_2 (columns POS_START and POS_END) and return a vector (length = nrow(dataframe_1)) that indicates which row of dataframe_1 lists a POS value that is within the range as indicated in dataframe_2.
Note that each POS value is linked to a particular CHR value.

Example return vector:

CHR     POS     EXAMPLE_RETURN_VECTOR

1       2000    TRUE

1       3000    FALSE

2       1500    TRUE

3       3000    FALSE

What’s the best strategy here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tribble(
     ~CHR, ~POS,
     1,  2000,                  
     1,  3000,
     2,  1500,
     3,  3000
)

df2 <- tribble(
     ~CHR, ~POS_START, ~POS_END,
     1, 1500, 2500,                  
     1, 3200, 4000,
     2, 1200, 1600,
     2, 2000, 2200,
     3, 5000, 5500,
     4, 1000, 1200
)

df1 %>% 
     left_join(df2, by = 'CHR') %>% 
     mutate(IN_RANGE = POS >= POS_START & POS <= POS_END) %>% 
     group_by(CHR, POS) %>% 
     summarize(IN_RANGE = sum(IN_RANGE) > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @RobertDurruthy-Durruthy awesome!  Could you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume that each `CHR` value only appears once?  Can we also assume that each `CHR` value that occurs in `dataframe_1` is also in `dataframe_2` and vice versa?  Can we also assume that both tables are sorted by the `CHR` value?  If so, you can just create a new column like this:

```
dataframe_1['NEW_COLUMN'] = dataframe_1.POS >= dataframe_2.POS_START & dataframe_1.POS <= dataframe_2.POS_END
```

If you can't make all of those assumptions, then you could either:

1) Merge both tables where they have matching `CHR` values, filter out rows with missing data, and then create the new column, or

2) Loop through each row of `dataframe_1`, and for each row, compare the `POS` value to the value of `dataframe_2[dataframe_2.POS_START == dataframe_1.POS_START]` and `dataframe_2[dataframe_2.POS_END == dataframe_1.POS_END]`